# Spatialite spatial queries do not function on GeoPackage

Tags: sql, spatialite, sqlite, geopackage, spatialite-gui

I have downloaded some data (as GeoPackages) from this excellent website: https://data.mfe.govt.nz/layer/52757-petroleum-wells/ and https://data.mfe.govt.nz/layer/52675-location-and-extent-of-nzs-aquifers-2015/ with the ultimate goal of writing a third GeoPackage where the two layers are related according to their spatial relationship (i.e. aquifers with references to intersecting wells).

QGIS is able to read these GeoPackages, and to display their geometries.

However when I use the Spatialite GUI (v4.3.0a) to query these datasets, I am running into odd geometry validation problems.

For example:

```
SELECT Count(*), GeometryType("geom"), Srid("geom"), CoordDimension("geom")
FROM "petroleum_wells"
GROUP BY 2, 3, 4
```

returns

```
1188    POINT    2193    NULL
```

i.e. that `CoordDimension("geom")` is `NULL`. This sensibly flows into literally every `ST_*` function I've tried: they all return `-1` for any function operating on the geometries, which is explained in the documentation as: "–1 for UNKNOWN corresponding to a function invocation on NULL arguments." However, the geometry itself is not NULL. It is returned as the outcome of a simple select, albeit with a rather funny tpyoe: `BLOB sz=47445 GeoPackegeGEOMETRY`.

Oddly, `ST_Is3D(geom)` correctly returns `0` (false) when it could return `-1` (unknown)... so it seems to have at least an understanding that's it's not in 3D.

`ST_IsValidReason(geom)` claims that the reason is `Invalid: NULL Geometry` even when I explicitly include a `WHERE "geom" IS NOT NULL` clause, and have successfully rendered the geometries in QGIS.

Is the GeoPackage geometry really invalid, or is there some issue with Spatialite, or some issue with the *way I am using* Spatialite?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The issue is with the way I am using Spatialite.

After talking with the company behind the web service that provides these datasets (since I initially assumed it may have been an export bug), they revealed to me that there is a distinction between *Spatialite geometries* and *GeoPackage geometries*.

To work with GeoPackages in Spatialite, there are several options:

- Use `GeomFromGPB()` or `AsGPB()` everywhere you're working with a GeoPackage geometry.
- Call `AutoGPKStart()` then use the `vgpkg_` prefixed names.
- (In Spatialite 4.3+) start queries with `SELECT EnableGpkgMode();`.

The last option is the easiest, and all spatial queries after that point "just work" as expected.