# How can I use spatial functions inside -csql with gdalwarp?

Tags: gdalwarp, geopackage

I'm using the following command to cut a GeoPackage from a GeoTIFF file:

```
gdalwarp -of GTiff -cutline input_database.gpkg -crop_to_cutline input_raster.tif output_raster.tif
```

Additionally, I know I can use `-csql` for making queries inside my GeoPackage database:

```
gdalwarp -of GTiff -cutline input_database.gpkg -csql "select geom from database" -crop_to_cutline input_raster.tif output_raster.tif
```

However, if I try to use any spatial function inside this query (like the `st_buffer()` function):

```
gdalwarp -of GTiff -cutline input_database.gpkg -csql "select st_buffer(geom,5) from database" -crop_to_cutline input_raster.tif output_raster.tif
```

I receive the error `ERROR 1: Failed to identify source layer from datasource`. While opening the GeoPackage with Spatialite, I can make this query work with [this solution](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/340180/173457). One of them is adding the function `GeomFromGPB()` on my geometries, but I've tested the last command with it and it didn't work as well. What am I missing? How can I use spatial functions on GeoPackages while using `gdalwarp` to cut the new geometry from a GeoTIFF file?

Comment: You need to specify SQL dialect ie  -dialect INDIRECT_SQLITE check the ogr2ogr documentation https://gdal.org/user/sql_sqlite_dialect.html

Comment: @kartoza-geek I think this option works only with `ogrinfo` and `ogr2ogr`. When I try to use it with `gdalwarp` I get the error `ERROR 6: Unknown option name '-dialect'`.

Comment: https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/gdal-dev/2014-October/040291.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, this can be done in two lines. Using first `ogr2ogr` and then `gdalwarp`:

```bsh
ogr2ogr -f GPKG -sql "select st_buffer(geom,5) from database"  bufferedOutput.gpkg input.gpkg
gdalwarp -of GTiff -cutline bufferedOutput.gpkg -crop_to_cutline input_raster.tif output_raster.tif
```

This is a functional solution. However, I didn't manage to use a query with `gdalwarp` where I can use spatial functions with the `-csql` parameter.